# GORM - read and write from/into separate tables

Tags: database, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm working on a Web application that allows user to amend some data in database. User specifies search criteria (for example name or surname), then the application searches data by given criteria, displays it on UI, user edits data and presses 'Save' button.

Currently all edits affect the same table (`person`). But I need to change application's logic: **read** operations (SELECT) should apply to one table (`person`). All **write** operations (INSERT, UPDATE, etc) should be applied to another table (`person_changes`). Is it possible to achieve such behavior via mapping or tuning another pure GORM settings? Or I need to develop HQL query for each SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE?

Now my domain class looks like this:

```
class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6023326467985259987L;

    String id
    String name
    String surname

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'stuff'
        table 'person'
        cache true
        version false
        id column: 'id', generator: 'assigned'
    }

    static constraints = {
        id(bindable: true, nullable: false, blank: false)
    }
}
```

I use *Grails 2.3.11* and *Hibernate 3.6.10.19*.

Comment: look into datasource ['stuff', 'main'] two DSN's then maybe you could extend Person class as PersonEdit class then make the datasource of this ''stuff' the one you want to write to. You will then automatically end up with 2 databases 1 containing real data and the other containing the real data + updates. You can then compare or whatever against both db's. It actually sounds like you just need to keep a history of the table changes in a historic table for reference instead of all this madness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve such behavior via mapping or tuning another pure GORM settings?

No

> Or I need to develop HQL query for each SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE?

HQL won't help you. Hibernate (and therefore GORM) fundamentally assumes that a persistent class is always read from and written to the same table

To be honest, this requirement sounds totally bizarre, if you're writing to a different table than you're reading from, how would you ever actually read anything?

Comment: Yes, it's strange requirement. Every month our organization imports database from CD (company policy - I cannot tell more here...). But sometimes this data is a little bit invalid (for example, missing surname, etc). So we need to apply small fixes for such datums. But now we are not allowed to change data in tables which came from CD. We created new table for holding all changes. So every changed datum appears in separate table (aka version control). I'm founding the simplest solution for splitting **read** and **write** operations (with minimal intervention in DAO layer).

Comment: I've found out that it is possible to negotiate the issue with aid of database rules (we use PostgreSQL actually) on INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE and database views. So there is not need to touch source code at all!